# How to customize the "multiple" attribute of a select tag in Symfony

Tags: symfony, drop-down-menu, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 and [Virtual Select](https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/), "A javascript plugin for dropdown with virtual scroll".

By default, when Symfony renders a multiple select, the HTML code looks like this :

```
<select multiple="multiple">
```

However, Virtual Select seems very picky, and only behaves properly if the multiple attribute doesn't have a value, like this :

```
<select multiple>
```

(Which, as far as I know, is the "official" syntax, multiple="multiple" isn't mentioned by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) for example.)

**Is there there a way to force Symfony to use the second syntax instead of the first ?**

I thought of a few workaround which wouldn't work :

- Writing the whole HTML myself wouldn't be practical as it is very long (hence Virtual Select).
- I tried passing the "multiple" option in Javascript as described [here](https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/properties?id=using-properties-on-initialization), but that has no effect if the the multiple attribute with the wrong syntax is still present in the HTML.
- I could replace Virtual Select, but I would rather not as it is already used in many other places.

Comment: How about not setting multiple in the Symfony form builder and just targeting the select id and setting multiple in the [Virtual Select initialise in js](https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/examples?id=multiple-select)..

Comment: If I did that, symfony would throw an error if multiple options were selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a workaround in javascript :

```
document.getElementById('select#whatever').setAttribute('multiple','');
```

Which seems to satisfy Virtual Select.

(And then I had to pile up more workarounds for other issues between Virtual Select and Symfony. All in all, you probably should avoid using those two together.)